# C# add anonymous list to typed list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am a little new to C#, sorry if the question is rudimentary.

I have an anonymous list as result of the following:

```
var Totals = model.Payments.GroupBy(pm => pm.PaymentType)
             .Select(t => new
               {
                    PaymentType = t.Key,
                    Amount = t.Sum(pm => pm.Amount)
               });
```

Returns Totals as anonymous list with two entries.

Cash        10000.00

EFT        8000.00

Now I need to add this list to a typed list in my viewmodel. The typed list looks like this

```
public class PaymentExportViewModel
{
    public List<PaymentReportViewModel> Payments { get; set; }
    public List<PaymentSubTotals> Subs { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public String VenueName { get; set;}
    public PaymentExportViewModel()
    {
        Payments = new List<PaymentReportViewModel>();
        Subs = new List<PaymentSubTotals>();
    }
}

public class PaymentSubTotals
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

So since I need to "convert" to typed I do this

```
PaymentSubTotals subs = new PaymentSubTotals();
foreach (var t in Totals)
{
    subs.Type = t.PaymentType;
    subs.Amount = t.Amount;
    model.Subs.Add(subs); 
}
```

The result is that model.subs now contains 2 entries but both are the same (last entry in my loop)
EFT        8000.00
EFT        8000.00

What am I missing in the model.Subs.Add ?  Or somewhere else ?

Comment: why project it to an anonymous type to begin with when you can just project it to a strongly typed class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move declation of subs inside of foreach loop:

```
foreach (var t in Totals)
{
    PaymentSubTotals subs = new PaymentSubTotals();
    subs.Type = t.PaymentType;
    subs.Amount = t.Amount;
    model.Subs.Add(subs); 
}
```

In your code you change the same sub object every time, so you do have only the data of the last t variable, repeated.

Comment: That is because in C#, when you add an item to a list it is passed by reference, not a copy, right? That's why when you modify `subs`, it modifies the item in the list?

Comment: @GustavoZanardini  yes, it's a reference type - class, so in the list are just n references to the same object.

Comment: Of course, I feel a little silly now.  Hopefully it can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you `Select` into your `PaymentSubTotals` instead.

```
var Totals = model.Payments.GroupBy(pm => pm.PaymentType)
.Select(t => new PaymentSubTotals
{
 Type = t.Key,
 Amount = t.Sum(pm => pm.Amount)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following method to add a new PaymentSubTotals object on each loop.

```
foreach (var t in Totals)
{
    model.Subs.Add(new PaymentSubTotals {
        Type = t.PaymentType;
        Amount = t.Amount;
    }); 
}
```